# Find a jQuery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I am using this piece of code to refresh/resize the main window when the search panel is collapsed and expanded. This currently works well with Chrome, IE 11 and Edge, but I fear that this will fail with other browsers.

So in my index.html file, I added Here I added the refreshWindow() to the ng-click on the `<div>` element.

```
<div class="cg-master-main-wrapper">
    <!-- slide left/expand sidebar -->
    <div class="cg-master-toggle-bar" ng-if="sidebar.left && sidebar.collapsible" ng-click="sidebar.hidden=!sidebar.hidden; refreshWindow()" ng-class="{'closed':sidebar.hidden, 'open':!sidebar.hidden}">
        <button class="cg-toggle-arrow" type="button">
           <span class="icon icon-1-75x" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-right':sidebar.hidden, 'icon-chevron-left':!sidebar.hidden}"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- main Content -->
    . . Other code . .
</div>
```

In my cgSessionController.js file, I created the refreshWindow() function

```
angular.module("cgCore").controller("cgSessionController", ["$scope", "$location", "$log", "$q", "$window", "$rootScope", "Idle", "Keepalive", "cgSessionService", "cgGlobals", "$timeout", "cgNavigationService", "cgBoHelper",
function ($scope, $location, $log, $q, $window, $rootScope, Idle, Keepalive, cgSessionService, cgGlobals, $timeout, cgNavigationService, cgBoHelper)
{
    . .Some Code. .

    $scope.refreshWindow = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
           var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
           evt.initEvent('resize', true, true);
           window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        });
    }

    . . Some More Code. .
}]);
```

How can I use jQuery to produce the same outcome?

I tried using `$(window).trigger('resize')`, but that did not work when I collapsed and expanded the search panel.

Any ideas would be great. 
Much appreciated.

Comment: can you show more code, some of your html and the where you call $(window).trigger('resize')

Answer (score 0):

You can [jQuery trigger](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```js
// Listen to resize 
$( window ).resize(function() {
  console.log('resize')
})

// Fire resize event manually, also you can resize the window to trigger the event!
var e = jQuery.Event( "resize" );
jQuery( window ).trigger( e );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Tareq, but your solution did not help.